# How do I make CSS Content italic and bold?

Tags: css

Okay so, I wanna make the CSS content class italic and bold.
Here's my code.

```css
div::before {
     content: "text";
     color:black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I wanna do it ***ONLY*** using CSS, no HTML.
The reason for this is because I am making a Discord Theme which is only possible with CSS, no custom HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `font-weight` and `font-style` properties to `::before` itself.

```css
div::before {
     content: "text";
     color:black;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make content *italic* using font-style and **bold** using font-weight

```
div {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First Add some text in div because this will allow you get difference then apply property of font-style: (normal or italic).

   **language: html**

Before >

After > Italic Text

```
 language: css

div::before {
     content: "text";
     color:black;
     font-style : italic;
}
```

Comment: i literally said im not gonna use html, its solved already

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Css Content Italic And Bold</title>
<style>
div::before {
     content: "text";
     color:black;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```